# What is the status of multiarch for 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, multiarch

What is the planned status of Multiarch support in 11.10?  In AMD64 Alpha 1, I attempted to install the i386 google chrome package using dpkg.  The install failed citing architecture mismatches, Is support for this kind of install planned or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Install 32-bit Compatibility Libraries

Have you tried installing the 32-bit libraries?

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

If that's installed, then navigate to the Chrome .deb package and use (to force installation):

```
sudo dpkg --force-architecture -i <name-of-package>.deb
```

And if things aren't working at first, try re-configuring the package manager:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Or...

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

---

### Download Native 64-bit Google Chrome

Alternatively, you can just install the native 64-bit Chrome package from [here at Google](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?platform=linux_ubuntu_x86_64).

Just remember that Oneiric is still in Alpha, many things can go wrong; don't be surprised if it doesn't work initially!

Reference:

[Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=912297)

Comment: Thanks for the dpkg info, I need to use a 32-bit browser to support the Juniper VPN which only works with a 32 bit browser/plugin

Comment: @Mark, glad to help. And as Jorge posted, Multi-arch will appear natively (hopefully soon) instead of through abstraction libraries. Sorry, I missed that bit of the question :S

Answer (score 2):

The plans for multiarch support in Oneiric are here:

- https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/foundations-o-multiarch-next-steps

(It could likely be broken in the Alpha)

Answer (score 1):

Multiarch is supported pretty well at this point (last time I tried was Beta 1). It's just that a package must be build with support for Multiarch. You can see whether a package was built for Multiarch by checking it dependencies for the `multiarch-support` package.

For a more in-depth answer on Multiarch, see [Is it possible to have 32 bit libraries installed on a 64 bit system?](https://askubuntu.com/q/60751/6969#60792)

Answer (score 1):

When I updated to Oneiric, I lost the ability to exec 32 bit bins. I was able to find the ia32-libs-multiarch package, which was what ultimately got me back and running.

Curiously, `aptitude install ia32-libs-multiarch` led to some grotesque and unexpected dependency issues (particularly, it broke on libmysqlclient16.) Using the old `apt-get` did the trick, however.