# Is it possible to have 32 bit libraries installed on a 64 bit system?

Tags: 64-bit

I have the 32 bit shared libraries installed, yet I am still getting this error while trying to install pogoplug:

```
./pogoplugfs: error while loading shared libraries: libfuse.so.2: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

Is there something else I need to do to get the program to load from the 32 bit libraries?

A similar question was asked earlier this year, but was not given any answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For some libraries, it's possible to have both the 32-bit and 64-bit libraries installed on a 64-bit system. This is available through the `ia32-libs` package on Ubuntu 10.04 and before. According to [the filelist of `ia32-libs`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/amd64/ia32-libs/filelist), there is no `libfuse.so.2` file included. That means that you cannot have both architectures installed at a time.

Since Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric, it's possible for packages to allow simultaneous installation for different architectures which is called "Multi-Arch". Unfortunately, if I may believe [the filelist of `libfuse2` on Oneiric](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/libfuse2), this package has not been transitioned yet. That can be determined from the package dependencies: if a package depends on `multiarch-support` (like [libdrm2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/libdrm2)), it has support for multi-arch support. However, this is *not* a guarantee that the package can be installed for multiple architectures simultaneously.

To query your local cache for the multi-arch capabilities of a package, say `libc6`, run:

```
apt-cache show libc6 | grep ^Multi-Arch:
```

For this command, the output is `Multi-Arch: same`. That means that both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of a package can be installed at a time. If there is no output, the package is not ready for multi-arch support. Other [possible values](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec#Binary_package_control_fields) are `foreign` (not co-installable, but it can be used to satisfy the dependencies of other architectures) and `allowed` (iirc, only one package is allowed to be installed at a time, but the package can be used to satisfy dependencies of other packages)

You should be able to install 32-bit packages on a 64-bit system with:

```
sudo apt-get install packagename:i386
```

#### Building 32-bit libfuse for 64-bit machines

Since the 32-bit fuse library is not supplied with `ia32-libs`, you've no other choice than building it yourself.

1. Install the build dependencies for fuse and get the source code:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ia32-libs libc6-i386
   sudo apt-get build-dep fuse
   apt-get source fuse
   ```
2. Configure the source tree and build fuse (adjust the directory name if needed):

   ```
   cd fuse-2.8.4
   CFLAGS=-m32 ./configure --host=i386-linux-gnu
   make -j 50
   ```
3. Install the 32-bit fuse library (adjust the version accordingly):

   ```
   sudo ln -s libfuse.so.2.8.4 /usr/local/lib/libfuse.so.2
   sudo install -m644 lib/.libs/libfuse.so.2.8.4 /usr/local/lib/
   ```
4. Update the linker cache:

   ```
   sudo ldconfig
   ```
5. (optional) Remove the source files:

   ```
   cd ..
   rm -r fuse-2.8.4
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Install ia32. Once that is done, you can now install any 32bit based programs on a 64bit platform.

Comment: I had ia32 installed (thats what I was talking about with the shared libraries). This only brought the error up with libfuse.so.2

Comment: `ia32-libs` does not contain all 32-bit libraries.